# delete some random rows from categories having more than 500 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some categories in which it has some number of rows..

in some categories contains very less rows, in some other categories contains some 5000 rows..

**What I need is:**
In a category some random rows should be deleted ONLY if in that catgeory has more than 500 rows.. overall in each category max 500 rows should be there..reamining rows should get deleted (no matter how many they're..)

iam not understanding how to write a query in mysql, could anyone pls help me on this..?

**EDITED:**
MY TABLE IS LIKE THIS CURRENTLLY..

```
**CATEGORIES|NO OF ROWS**
========================
CAT1|500
CAT2|5000
CAT3|20
CAT4|50
CAT5|4000
```

**where NO OF ROWS** : COUNT OF ALL ROWS FROM THAT RESPECTIVE CATEGORY!

NOW CAT2 AND CAT5 ARE HAVING MORE THAN 500 ROWS, SO REMAINING ROWS SHOULD GET DELETED FROM THESE 2 CATEGORIES.. (**NOTE:** I DONT BOTHER WHAT ROWS GETTING DELETED, YOU CAN DELETE THEM IN RANDOM..)

Comment: Suggest you improve your question: it is not clear.

Comment: What is the schema of the categories table?

Comment: Please, explain more. What do you mean with that categories have more rows? Where are those rows?

Comment: Does it have to be random?

Comment: @Strawberry I edited Above, could you please check now!

Comment: @Legionar I edited Above, could you please check now!

Comment: Ok, I see.. and that rows are in another table, yes?

Comment: @Legionar rows are in that same table only.. "NO OF ROWS" means: Count of all rows from that respective category!

Comment: I understand, that no. of rows are in that same category, that I can see. But I am asking, from where (which table) you want to delete random rows of category, which has no. of rows > 500?!

Comment: @Legionar i have only 1 table, the above table came when i run query: select categories, count(*) from mytable group by categories

and what you udnerstood is correct.. I mean YES for this:   you want to delete random rows of category, which has no. of rows > 500

Comment: @RaymondNijland i really not understanding on how to write query my above requirement. you might ask why is such requirement, but that is what I've currently.. could you pls tell me writing query for above..

Comment: @user2889661 your question looks incomplete  you only are showing an summery of cats/count within?  you should also have an category table right? can you post an SQL show create table  output here?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i dont know how to explain, BUT i had only 1 table and some columns.. 'categories' is one of the column in that table..

Comment: @user2889661 if you don't know how to explain i certainly not going to understand. really lost you right now maybe you can post your table(s) and some example data on sqlfiddle ... www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @RaymondNijland please do not think too much.. ok, you can assume like this: one table with only 2 columns (dept, emps)

so, in each row, data would be something like: dept1, emp1; dept1, emp2; dept2, emp3, dept2 emp4  so on.. so, when you make a query as : select dept, emps from myTable group by dept, you can get output as showned above.. (except column names chnaged..) I guess i explained clearly... so, could you pls show query for my prob now.?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (category_id INT NOT NULL,val INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(category_id,val));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,101),(1,102),(1,103),(1,104),(2,103),(2,104),(2,105),(3,104),(3,105),(4,106);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-------------+-----+
| category_id | val |
+-------------+-----+
|           1 | 101 |
|           1 | 102 |
|           1 | 103 |
|           1 | 104 |
|           2 | 103 |
|           2 | 104 |
|           2 | 105 |
|           3 | 104 |
|           3 | 105 |
|           4 | 106 |
+-------------+-----+

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.category_id = x.category_id 
   AND RAND(y.val) <= RAND(x.val) 
 GROUP 
    BY x.category_id
     , x.val
 ORDER BY category_id
     , rank;
+-------------+-----+------+
| category_id | val | rank |
+-------------+-----+------+
|           1 | 104 |    1 |
|           1 | 101 |    2 |
|           1 | 102 |    3 |
|           1 | 103 |    4 |
|           2 | 104 |    1 |
|           2 | 105 |    2 |
|           2 | 103 |    3 |
|           3 | 104 |    1 |
|           3 | 105 |    2 |
|           4 | 106 |    1 |
+-------------+-----+------+
```

So, say we want to consider all rows ranked higher than '2', then this query can be rewritten as follows...

```
 SELECT x.*
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.category_id = x.category_id 
    AND RAND(y.val) <= RAND(x.val) 
  GROUP 
     BY x.category_id
      , x.val
 HAVING COUNT(*)> 2;
```

...which can then be transposed to a DELETE by the simple agency of a JOIN

```
 DELETE a FROM my_table a
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT x.*
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.category_id = x.category_id 
           AND RAND(y.val) <= RAND(x.val) 
         GROUP 
            BY x.category_id
             , x.val
        HAVING COUNT(*)> 2
      ) b 
     ON b.category_id = a.category_id
    AND b.val = a.val;

 Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.08 sec)

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +-------------+-----+
 | category_id | val |
 +-------------+-----+
 |           1 | 101 |
 |           1 | 104 |
 |           2 | 104 |
 |           2 | 105 |
 |           3 | 104 |
 |           3 | 105 |
 |           4 | 106 |
 +-------------+-----+
 7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: BUT I need a delete statement.. BTW, i edited above, could you please check above and rewrite your query..

Comment: Iam not that good at writing sql queries extensively.. i can able to write only normal queries for now.. iam still learning it.. so, could you help me providing query for this...?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you enough.

```
DELETE FROM TABLENAME 

WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME > 500)

ORDER BY RAND() 

LIMIT 10
```

Limit 10 is the number of deletions you want.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() is the random function in mysql

Comment: this needs to take into consideration >500 rows PER category, not a table with more than 500 rows

Comment: And did you even tryed ORDER BY RAND() on large tables lets say greater then 100.000 records, i think not because this will make execution very very slow..

Comment: You're right, but with the information he gave, I suposed that they are not big tables, less than 1000. But if there are big tables, you have to refine the query to improve the execution time.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Actually iam not understanding how to write query for this kinda requirement.. i can just write normal queries..

Comment: @user2889661 ive made an comment on your quention "@ the top"

Answer (score -1):

**Hi,**

AS per my understand you have one CategoryDetails TABLE which have multiple records per CategoryID. AND you need to maintain maximum 500 records per CategoryID.

AS per above understanding I am giving you below solution using SQL CTE. If I ma wrong then please explain your query IN detail.

> ```
> WITH cteCategoryDetails AS (
> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID, STATE ORDER BY CategoryID) AS RowNum  FROM CategoryDetails
> ) DELETE FROM cteCategoryDetails WHERE RowNum > 500
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**

Comment: MySQL doesn't have CTE's, nor row-number()